# ksh - pipe cannot write to output

Tags: pipe, ksh, tail

i use this line in a ksh (not ksh93) under AIX 6.1

```
# initiate earlier
LineStart=235559
cst_TracorTailLook=128
FileName=/LongPathWithSlash/logs/file.log
# /LongPathWithSlash/logs/file.log -> file_log.27Jun2014-00:00:00
# File is about 250.000 line and 60.000.000 bytes or more 

# the failing line
tail -n +$(( ${LineStart} - ${cst_TracorTailLook} + 1 )) ${FileName} |
    SomeAction
```

running in direct session, no problem, it return the result (test with a `wc -l` after pipe return a number of line) but running from and agent (Tivoli monitoring agent) this line return:

```
tail: 0652-046 Cannot write to output.
There is no process to read data written to a pipe.
```

Loking for limitation i found less limitation (`ulimit-a`) from the agent than direct session

```
                     Direct      Agent
time(seconds)        unlimited   unlimited
file(blocks)         unlimited   unlimited
data(kbytes)         131072      unlimited
stack(kbytes)        32768       32768
memory(kbytes)       32768       32768
coredump(blocks)     2097151     unlimited
nofiles(descriptors) 2000        unlimited
threads(per process) unlimited   unlimited
processes(per user)  unlimited   unlimited
```

I found several issue on AIX 5.3 about limitation to 2 Gb but this is not the size nor the OS version

Eventually, is there an alternative without passing through temporary file ?

Comment: after lot of anaylyze, the cause was due to pipe on file was "lost" because of the modification of the file in short time and use of memory. More memory could certainly help but is not possible, solution was (unhopefully) to extract the info to a temporary file and work from this one

Answer (score 1):

When the SomeAction after the pipe is finished before the tail is finished, you will have a broken pipe.
Make sure your SomeAction will wait until tail is finished.

Comment: any tested action failed (wc -l, a simple sed, sum, ...)

Comment: maybe the pipe is broken by Tivoli:
[link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v61r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.itm.doc_6.3%2Finstall%2Ftems_envvar.htm) Specifies the time in seconds that Agent Deployment tool has to complete a task. If the tool does not complete in the task in the time specified by the TIMEOUT value, the task is terminated. The default value is 600 seconds.

Comment: How to solve? You do not want the agent start the script again when the previous one is still running. Actually you would like the agent to perform a simple check. Can you make a crontab entry that does SomeAction with your logfile and reports it in a simple file? Tivoli than just needs to check the condensed result file from crontab. (Another question would be how to optimize a script that is watching a logfile)

Comment: Reproduce errormessage: `#!/bin/ksh
TESTFILE="something"
 
function testpipe
{
   typeset -i count=1 maxcount=$1
   print "Testing $maxcount output lines ..."
 
   while [ $count -le $maxcount ]; do
      echo $count >> ${TESTFILE}
      print "Output line $count"
      ((count+=1))
   done | head -1 > /dev/null
}
testpipe 50000 2>&1
rm ${TESTFILE} 2>/dev/null
`

Comment: Timeout on script is not the case (following instruction and there is a lot) are working fine. Timeout is 300 sec in our case and previous script is not woring anymore (start of script is checking it and have a quit sequence for this case). The crontab is not possible (security reason in firm and result of script is the input for tivoli agent so, adding level is not available for such a simple file check). Anyway thanks for all those point to check

Comment: With a broken link the first program still continues, the command after the pipe just gave up: I am not sure the timeout is not the problem. I'll post another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the script that is called by the agent is finished in 10 seconds.
Tailing the large logfiles should be done "outside" the agent.
You said crontab is not possible here, maybe you can fire a background process:

```
LASTRESULT="cat ${ResultAction}"
nohup SomeAction > ${ResultAction} 2>&1 &
```

Of course this way your agent does not have the latest result, so be aware to start the agent often. Not too often, you do not want concurrent (background) processes scanning your output.
(Check this in your current solution as well).

Can you make the logfile you are monitoring smaller? Turn off debug logging or rotating the file more often ? Does the program that is writing the logfile closing the filedescriptor after each log-action?

```
timestamp=${your_layout_yyyymmdd_hhmm}
mv ${FileName} ${FileName}.${timestamp}
touch ${FileName}
# I think Now you do not want to use a 
# tail -n +${offset} ${FileName}.${timestamp} | SomeAction
# and you are happy with
cat ${FileName}.${timestamp} | SomeAction
```

Comment: tail is made in `real    0m0.04s user    0m0.00s sys     0m0.00s`so the 10 sec are ok. The tail is only a part to take the 128 line previous last time checked [ to extract last non empty line] (while log is still feeded) and treat file from extracted info. A external process for this will desynchronise too much. The same script work on the rest of our server even with lot bigger files (not same hardware) on same OS.

Comment: log file is not on my own and i have to take it (no copy, modification, ...) as is and is is often still feeded during my script